# Problema no TextBox para fazer autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, linq

Não consigo entrar no método que faz a query para me devolver os `nomes` e os `id´s` da pessoa.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    });
    $("#AutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var pessoa = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("GetAutoComplete", "Catequizando"))",
                data: { "term": request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                        pessoa[i] = { label: data[i].nome, Id: data[i].id };
                    }
                }
            });
            response(pessoa);
        }
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CriarCatequizando", "Catequizando", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Introduza o nome do Pai:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">

            @Html.TextBox("AutoComplete", null, new { autofocus = "", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAutoComplete(string term)
{
    // se o termo a pesquisar for nulo...
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term))
    {
        term = "";
    }
    // procura as pessoas com nomes começados pelo valor especificado em 'term'
    // a lista está limitada a 10 pessoas
    var pessoas = (from pessoa in db.Pessoa
                   where pessoa.Nome.StartsWith(term)
                   orderby pessoa.Nome ascending
                   select new
                   {
                       id = pessoa.PessoaID,
                       nome = pessoa.Nome
                   }).Take(10);

    // devolve a lista de pessoas
    return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Como esse autocomplete é chamado? Qual componente para autocomplete você está usando?

Comment: Por lapso, esqueci me de por o script. Foi editado.

Comment: Você recebe algum erro no console do browser (F12)? Retire o `HttpPost` e acesse manual sua action, para ver se está retornando o `JSON` corretamente.